# Nested group query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of Answers:

```
 Answer.last
 Answer Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" ORDER BY "answers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Answer id: 235, question_id: 15, choice_id: 23, user_id: 3, created_at: "2013-08-28 23:51:24", updated_at: "2013-08-28 23:51:24", club_id: 11>
```

As you can see, each Answer belongs to a question, choice, user and club. I'm trying to create a nested group query to produce a hash of:

```
 { club_id { choice_id => answers_count, choice_id => answers_count}, etc, etc }
```

What I have so far:

```
 Answer.where(:question_id => 14).group(:club_id, :choice_id).count
```

Which produces:

```
{[4, 21]=>7, [11, 21]=>2, [4, 22]=>4, [11, 22]=>7}
```

This is:

```
{ [club_id, choice_id] => answers_count, etc, etc }
```

Is there anyway to do what I require in one query or will I have to merge/re-jig this hash? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You've got the query. What you need to do is restructure it.

Comment: Thanks tadman. Any idea how I can restructure this to {4{21 => 7,22 => 4}, 11 {21 => 2,22 => 7}}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @tadman says, the result you're seeing is all the query can get you.  If you want a custom format, you'll need to run it through an algorithm.  Something like this should work for you:

```
result = Answer.where(:question_id => 14).group(:club_id, :choice_id).count

better_result = result.each_with_object({}) do |((club_id, choice_id), answers_count), m|
  m[club_id] ||= {}
  m[club_id][choice_id] = answers_count
end
```