# Passing hash data to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash

I have a nested hash I've created from a previous question of mine [Nested group query in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520100/nested-group-query-in-rails)

The hash now being:

```
   {14=>{11=>{21=>7, 22=>8}, 4=>{21=>7, 22=>4}}, 16=>{5=>{25=>2, 26=>1}, 11=>{26=>2, 25=>5}} }
```

I want to pass this data to javascript and I think it will be best to have key names for each attribute/model like so:

```
   { question_id: 14=>{ club_id: 11=>{ choice_id: 21=>7, choice_id: 22=>8} etc etc}
```

My question is, would this be a best practice to pass data in Rails to Javascript or would it be better to do this from a json variable from the controller.

If the approach I'm trying is fine, is there a way to set key names in a hash as my attribute names from my initial query?

```
Answer.where(:question_id => 14).group(:club_id, :choice_id).count
```

Thanks

Comment: the syntax in the second code snippet is invalid. there is no best practice. how you send it to the client depends on your application. if the data is available when you generate the page then you can emit it with the rest of the page. if you are using ajax and it is available then, then use ajax.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: Thanks akonsu, The data wont be available when the page is generated. I think I'm going to pass it through json as the js framework I'm using can handle this. Do you know if it's possible to add in my app attribute names as the keys?

Answer (score 0):

There is no structure like that:

```
 { question_id: 14 => { club_id: 11 => { choice_id: 21 => 7, choice_id: 22 => 8 }
```

You're trying to associate a hash value with further values, which is an invalid structure. One way to achieve a semantic structure (meaning a structure which reflects the actual relationships of your counts and id's to each other) for your data so you can pass it to the browser via `JSON` would be to build a hash like the following:

```
{ questions: [
  { 
    id: 14,
    clubs: [
      {
        id: 11,
        choices: [
          {
            id: 21,
            count: 7
          },
          {
            id: 22,
            count: 8
          }
        ]
      }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```